Zoom in on a specific region of a plot
I have these two plots in the following:
plt1 = ContourPlot[{x^2 + 2 y^2}, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
  Contours -> {10000}, ContourShading -> {Pink, None}];

Plot[{(-0.001688 - 0.97 x)/-1.587, (
  0.001688 - 0.97 x)/-1.587}, {x, -100, 100}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.7]}, PlotStyle -> Blue];

Show[plt1, plt2]

I would like to zoom (-0.005,0.005) range in the x-axis and (-0.1,0.1) range in the y-axis and show the zoomed-in region in the same plot. How can I do that?

Is your question similar to 210815?

@Syed, Yes. I solved the problem. Thanks.
